# Enable "Community Site Feature" on a subsite site, will prevent users from accessing it unless they have contribute permision on the root site

Tags: 2013, permissions, administration, my-site, community-site

I am working on an on-premises team site collections 2013. now the site collection have some sub-sites which have unique permissions. and for certain users they only have contribute permission on the sub-site without any permission on the root site. and every thing was working well. where inside the sub-site i have many custom lists, document library & discussion board lists and users can view/add/edit/delete items from the sub-site even if they do not have any permission on the root site.

but today i have enabled the " Community Site Feature", because i want to allow users to mention each other inside the discussion board lists. but i have noted that any user who do not have any permission on the root site will no longer be able to access the sub-site home page, where they will get the following error on the sub-site home page:

> Sorry, you don't have access to this page

now if i grant them Read permission on the root the same problem will still happening, but if i grant them contribute on the root the problem will be solved, but of course i do not want to do this!!

now users who do not have any permission on the root site, can access all the lists directly and can create items, but the problem will happen when they are redirected to the sub-site home page they will get the above error!! although the site home page was not affected when i enable the " Community Site Feature".. the thing which happened when i enable this feature is that a new discussion list was created,and many links were added inside the quick launch links.. but i remove these links from the quick launch links, as i thought that this was causing the problem...
so can anyone adivce on this ? how i can have users accessing the sub-sites without having to grant them any permission on the root site... as when things were working well before enabling the "Community Site Feature" feature inside the sub-sites?

**EDIT.**
I did a further investigation on this, i have noted that when i enable the "Community Site Feature" the built-in site Pages library will got a unique permission and  will only include certain groups.. so not sure why this will happen, and will there be any drawback if i force the Page to inherit the permission back?